# Why would you set a shader program inside a game loop?

Tags: opengl

I'm going through an OpenGL tutorial and in the code examples the functions `glGetUniformLocation` and `glUseProgram` are called unconditionally inside of the main game loop.

It seems like it would be a waste to do this once a frame, and the program still behaves correctly after moving this logic to before the start of the game loop. Are there any reasons for keeping this logic inside the game loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetUniformLocation needs only be called when the shader is initialized. glUseProgram might be useful if you later store which program is used in some variable.